# Using Jinja2 {{ variable }} into {% instructions %} with Django

Tags: django, jinja2

I try to setup a webp image converter into my Django templates this way :

```
<img alt="background" src={% webp "/static/img/{{ article.image }}" %} alt="{{ article.name }}" />
```

It returns me an escape string like this (for exemple in a Jinja loop) :

```
<img alt="background" src="/static/static/img/%7B%7B%20article.image%20%7D%7D">
```

Is there a way to combinate both in a clean way ?

NB : it works in debug False but in production it returns me a 400 Bad Request with no details.

Thanks !

Comment: Take a look at the [`add` template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#add)

Comment: Thanks. I've try this :

<img alt="background" src="{{ article.image|webp_img }}" alt="{{ article.name }}" />

With a templatetags/webp_img.py :

from django import template
from django.template import Template

register = template.Library()
@register.filter
def webp_img(img):
    result = '{% webp "/static/img/' + img + '" %}'
    return result

It returns me <img alt="background" src="{% webp &quot;/static/img/mediumnite.jpg&quot; %}">

Did I miss something ?

Comment: You mention Jinja2 in the title and tags, but the traceback shows `from django import template from django.template` so it looks like you are using regular Django templates.

Comment: drec4s was suggesting to use the add filter like this: `{% webp "/static/img/"|add:article.image %}`

Comment: Oh ok, it works, thanks !! :)